# Is a martingale with bounded variance therefore bounded in $L^2$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

If a martingale $W_n$ has bounded variance, does this mean that $W_n$ is automatically bounded in $L^2$? I feel like this ought to be obvious but I don't see how to prove it and I haven't been able to find any references.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Can the sequence E(W_n) be *unbounded*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the martingale property,

$$
\begin{align}
\text{E}(W_n) &= \text{E}[\text{E}(W_n | W_{n - 1})] \\
&= \text{E}(W_{n - 1}) \\
&= ... \\
&= \text{E}(W_1) ,
\end{align}
$$

and so you have a uniform bound on both  $\text{Var}(W_n)$ and $\text{E}(W_n)^2$.

Comment: No problem.  Technically I left out the minor (but important) detail that $|\text{E}(W_1)| \leq \text{E}(|W_1|) < \infty$, also by the definition of martingale.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you take a random variable $\xi$ which is $L^{1}$ but not $L^{2}$. Let that 
$$M_{n} = \xi,\quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
Then this constant martingale is obviously not $L^{2}$ but with bounded variation.

---

However, in contunuous time, If a martingale starts at $0$ and has bounded variation. Then this martingale is almost surely equals to $0$ along the path.